# MaxDegreeOfParallelism with Task.Factory.StartNew()

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

I have a program where I download files from the Internet and process them. Following is the function that I have written to download the file using threads.

```
Task<File> re = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { /*Download the File*/ });
re.ContinueWith((x) => { /*Do another function*/ });
```

I now want it to use only 10 threads for downloading. I have looked in to **ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism** property, but I can't understand how to use it when the task returns a result.

Comment: Are you going to download 10 files in parallel? Once the file download is finished, is the other function that you continue with CPU intensive?

Comment: I want only 10 files to be download parallel in a given time. There are like 100 files and the other function is CPU intensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good way to do that is to use the [DataFlow API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx). To use it, you have to install the [Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow).

Assuming that you have the following methods for downloading and processing data:

```
public async Task<DownloadResult> DownloadFile(string url)
{
    //Asynchronously download the file and return the result of the download.
    //You don't need a thread to download the file if you use asynchronous API.
}

public ProcessingResult ProcessDownloadResult(DownloadResult download_result)
{
    //Synchronously process the download result and produce a ProcessingResult.    
}
```

And assuming that you have a list of URLs that you want to download:

```
List<string> urls = new List<string>();
```

Then you can do the following with the DataFlow API:

```
TransformBlock<string,DownloadResult> download_block =
    new TransformBlock<string, DownloadResult>(
        url => DownloadFile(url),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            //Only 10 asynchronous download operations
            //can happen at any point in time.
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
        });

TransformBlock<DownloadResult, ProcessingResult> process_block =
    new TransformBlock<DownloadResult, ProcessingResult>(
        dr => ProcessDownloadResult(dr),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            //We limit the number of CPU intensive operation
            //to the number of processors in the system.
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
        });

download_block.LinkTo(process_block);

foreach(var url in urls)
{
    download_block.Post(url);
}
```

Comment: Any comment for the down vote? I am really interested to know if there is an issue with this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
Func<File> work = () => {
    // Do something
    File file = ...
    return file
};

var maxNoOfWorkers = 10;    
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, maxNoOfWorkers)
    .Select(s =>
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<File>(work);
        return task.ContinueWith(ant => { /* do soemthing else */ });        
    });
```

This way `TPL` decides how many threads to get from the `threadpool` if however you really want to create a dedicated (`non-threadpool`) thread you can then do so using:

```
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, maxNoOfWorkers)
    .Select(s =>
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<File>(
            work, 
            CancellationToken.None, 
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
            TaskScheduler.Default);
        return task.ContinueWith(ant => { /* do soemthing else */ });
    });
```

Your other options would be to use `PLINQ` or `Paraller.For/ForEach` which you can use the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` with.

A `PLINQ` example can be:

```
Func<File> work = () => {
    // Do something
    File file = ...
    return file
};

var maxNoOfWorkers = 10;
ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, maxNoOfWorkers)
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(maxNoOfWorkers)
    .ForAll(x => { 
        var file = work();
        // Do something with file
    });
```

Of course I don't know the context of your example so you may need to adapt it to your requirement.